# Sending mail with attachments from Oracle apex

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-apex

In oracle 11gR2 database I create a directory named 'my_directory' there are some pdf file. In Oracle apex i want to send mail with attachments. Is't possible to attach file from this directory? If possible, How?
APEX version: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file as a BLOB and then attach using [APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI341)